# VHDL , Division using storing algorithm..the code is not working

Tags: vhdl, division

I wrote a simple code that divides (Numerator, Denominator) using restoring algorithm. The syntax is fine but in the simulation I only get "11111111" in the quotient!

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity DIV_8bit is
    Port ( 
          Numerator : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
          Denominator : in  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
          Quotient : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0);
          Remainder : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(7 downto 0)
          );
 end DIV_8bit;

 architecture Behavioral of DIV_8bit is
 begin
   process(Numerator , Denominator)
     variable Num: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := Numerator;
     variable p :std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
     variable Den: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := Denominator;
     variable i : integer :=0;
   begin
     Division_loop: for i in 0 to 7 loop
       p(7 downto 1) := p(6 downto 0);
       p(0) := Num(7);
       Num(7 downto 1) := Num(6 downto 0) ;
       p := p - Den;
       if (p < 0) then
         P := P + Denominator;
         Num(0) := '0';
       else 
         Num(0) := '1';
       end if ;
     end loop;
     Quotient <= Num;
     Remainder <= p;
   end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the package `ieee.std_logic_unsigned`. Instead use the package `ieee.numeric_std`. This package defines the data-types `unsigned` and `signed` as  sub-types of `std_logic_vector`. Theses types tell the compiler how to interpret the bit-sequence as a number. This package also allows to mix both unsigned and signed numbers in one module which is not possible with `ieee.std_logic_unsigned`.

Among others, the package defines appropiate operators to compare `unsigned` / `signed` with integers.

To convert to and from `std_logic_vector`, for example if your inputs and outputs are of this type, just use the following type conversions (shown here as functions, but actually they are not):

```
function std_logic_vector(x : unsigned)         return std_logic_vector;
function std_logic_vector(x :   signed)         return std_logic_vector;
function signed          (x : std_logic_vector) return signed;
function unsigned        (x : std_logic_vector) return unsigned;
```

You can also convert from and to integers:

```
function to_integer (x : unsigned) return integer;
function to_integer (x :   signed) return integer;
function to_unsigned(x: integer; size : natural)   return unsigned;
function to_signed  (x: integer; size : natural)   return signed;
```

There is lot of more nice stuff in the package `ieee.numeric_std` such as arithmetic operators with integers, sign extension and much more.

Comment: The first three 'functions' are not. type conversion is a basic operation,  an explicit type conversion is of the form `type_mark(operand)` and only works between closely related types (and std_logic_vector, signed and unsigned are closely related See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.3.6 Type conversions). `to_unsigned` and `to_signed` have two arguments in package numeric_std, the second argument `size` with is a natural and has no default value.

Comment: @user1155120 You are right, I missed the `size` argument. I used the function syntax for the type conversion here because it it easier to understand than the explanation in the IEEE standard. Added a note about that.